# Subset selection in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I have many calendars in Google Calendar, and I would like to be able to quickly switch from viewing one set of calendars to another set. This is extremely useful when planning, where I have several calendars for potential events of different categories, each in a separate calendar. I know *Fantastical* (on Mac OS) has this function, but $50 is way too much for just this one capability.

I could manually click the calendar icons on Google Calendar web interface to switch between, but that's quite a number of clicks. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just a note: We don't accept questions asking for app (or extension) recommendations. You have a good problem statement, though, so I've simply edited out that part of your question. See also: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)